# skip update for particular field in solr

Tags: solr, solrclient

I want to skip update of particular field in solr document.

I am importing data from csv to solr. added one extra field **"RecCount"** from managed schema as follows:

**Case 1:** If i set default value

```
<field name="RecCount" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
```

when i re import data then previous value of RecCount field reset to 0 which i don't want if it is 5 then it need not to be update.

**Case 2:** if no default value

```
<field name="RecCount" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

in this case when i re-import data **"RecCount"** field is not getting added to document

Import shell script as follows :

```
wget "$1" -O $DOWNLOADFILE
$SOLR_URL -c $SOLR_CORE $DOWNLOADFILE
```

What is the way to skip update of **RecCount** field?

Comment: So what is your _actual update_ request? It seems like you're just sending the same index request to Solr, and not asking for an update. If you want to _update a document_ (and not index a new one over the old one), you [have to format your requests in a specific way](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/updating-parts-of-documents.html).

Answer (score 1):

The csv index handler allows to set a parameter called "skip" which takes the field names to skip during import.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-update-parameters